# Threading, multiprocessing shared memory and asyncio

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-asyncio

I am having trouble implementing the following scheme :

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.content = []
        self.current_len = 0

    def __len__(self):
        return self.current_len

    def update(self, new_content):
        self.content.append(new_content)
        self.current_len += 1

class B:
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id
```

And I also have these 2 functions that will be called later in the main :

```
async def do_stuff(first_var, second_var):
    """ this function is ideally called from the main in another 
        process. Also, first_var and second_var are not modified so it 
        would be nice if they could be given by reference without 
        having to copy them """

    ### used for first call
    yield None
    while len(first_var) < CERTAIN_NUMBER:
        time.sleep(10)

    while True:
        ## do stuff
        if condition_met:
            yield new_second_var ## which is a new instance of B
        ## continue doing stuff

def do_other_stuff(first_var, second_var):
    while True:
        queue = multiprocessing.JoinableQueue()
        results = multiprocessing.Queue()
        ### do stuff
        first_var.update(results)
```

The main looks like this at the moment :

```
first_var = A()
second_var = B()
while True:
    async for new_second_var in do_stuff(first_var, second_var):
        if new_second_var:
            ## stop the do_other_stuff that is currently running
            ## to re-launch it with the updated new_var
            do_other_stuff(first_var, new_second_var)
        else: ## used for the first call
            do_other_stuff(first_var, second_var)
```

Here are my questions :

- Is there a better solution to make this scheme work?
- How can I implement the "stopping" part since there is a while True loop that fills first_var by reference?
- Will the instance of A (first_var) be passed by reference to do_stuff if first_var doesn't get modified inside it?
- Is it even possible to have an asynchronous generator in another process?
- Is it even possible at all?

This is using Python 3.6 for the async generators.

I hope this is somewhat clear! Thanks a lot!

Comment: So I can answer some of the questions myself after thinking and searching a bit more about it. 3/ No, since it is a complete difference process, the values will be copied unless I use multiprocessing.Array or multiprocessing.Value which I can't do since my first_var is an instance of a class. 4/ I can work around it and modify my do_stuff function to return and end the process as soon as the condition is met, and restarting it with the newly returned value

Comment: Why is `do_stuff` an `async def`? It doesn't seem to `await` anything, and it uses `time.sleep` which indicates a blocking function rather than an asyncio coroutine.

Comment: Yes, this is my bad !

Comment: Do you mean that `do_stuff` shouldn't be `async`? It's really hard to figure out from the question what you actually want to accomplish.